# How to know the path the script the python run?

Tags: python, path

sys.arg[0] gives me the python script. For example 'python hello.py' returns hello.py for sys.arg[0]. But I need to know where the hello.py is located in full path.

How can I do that with python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import sys
print(sys.path[0])
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> As initialized upon program startup,
>   the first item of this list, sys.path[0],
>   is the directory containing the script
>   that was used to invoke the Python
>   interpreter.

Answer (score 6):

```
os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `__file__`, a variable that contains the full path to the module from which you access it. This doesn't necessarily have to end with the ".py" extension, but can also be ".pyc" (or `None`).

There is also [documentation available on __file__](http://docs.python.org/library/runpy.html).

Comment: See info on the Module object's predefined attributes in the documentation here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types (the link in the answer is wrong).