# How to know the directory where the python script is called?

Tags: python, path

Let's say that I have a python script a.py in /A/B/a.py, and it's in the PATH environment variable. The current working directory is /X/Y/, and it's the directory where I call the /A/B/a.py.

- In a.py, how to detect /X/Y/? I mean, how to know in which directory the python call is made?

Comment: The directory in which the python call is made is automatically the working directory.

Comment: No it is not, please copy a script to Windows directory, and run getcwd(), anywhere we get output c:\windows not c:\working_folder

Comment: @kephalian - I have just tested the following code from a non-admin command prompt in various directories in Windows 11 and it seems to work fine:

`C:\xxxx > python -c "import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Previous comment was because of a configuration in VisualStudio code that caused it to execute in folder of py.exe.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can get the current working directory with:

```
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: You should use `getcwdu()` for portability reasons.

Comment: The function [`getcwdu`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwdu) returns a unicode string in Python 2. [`getcwd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd) in Python 3 returns a unicode string. [`getcwdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwdb) returns a bytestring in Python 3. There is no `getcwdu` in Python 3.

Answer (score 8):

```
>> os.getcwd()
/X/Y
>> os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))   # cannot be called interactively
/A/B
>> sys.path[0]
/A/B
>> os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
/A/B/a.py
```

Comment: That gives you the `/A/B` directory, the location of the `a.py`.

Comment: That's not what he meant, see his question from yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691921/how-to-know-the-path-the-script-the-python-run).

Comment: @Radomir — I thought the directory where the .py file resides is what the OP wanted. Your comment made me reread the OP's question, and see that that is not the case.

Comment: If the script is called from path, os.getcwd() returns windows C:\Windows  and not path where is executed say C:\Workingfolder